# Display ContactName from Guid in Gridview using SQLDataSource / Asp.Net

Tags: sql, asp.net

I have set the following code up to display player1 v player2 in a Gridview. However, It currently displays tblFixtures.player1 v tblFixtures.player2 which are UniqueIdentifiers, I need it to display their corresponding contact names instead. tblaccounts has columns accountID(uniqueidentifier)  and contactName(varchar) but not sure how to join this in such a way that I can display them in the Gridview below.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="DSFixtures" runat="server" ConnectionString="
<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT 
tblFixtures.player1, tblFixtures.player2, tblFixtures.compID, 
tblFixtures.round
FROM tblFixtures INNER JOIN tblCompetitions ON tblFixtures.compID = 
tblCompetitions.compID WHERE tblFixtures.compID = @Event_ID and round = 
@Round ">

<SelectParameters>
    <asp:QueryStringParameter QueryStringField="compID" Name="Event_ID" />
    <asp:QueryStringParameter QueryStringField="round" Name="Round" />
</SelectParameters>

</asp:SqlDataSource>

        <asp:Gridview ID="gdvFixtures" visible="false" width="100%"  
            runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            CssClass="mGrid" DataKeyNames="compID" DataSourceID="DSFixtures" 
            PageSize="20" AllowSorting="True">

            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt" />
            <Columns>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="player1" HeaderText="player1" />
                <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        V
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="player2" HeaderText="player2" />

            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a nested select

```
SELECT tblFixtures.player1, (SELECT name FROM tblaccounts WHERE
  (accountID = tblFixtures.player1)) AS player1_name, ...
```

Or create another 2 joins, one for each player. You can do that by renaming the tables with `AS` so you can join the same table multiple times.

```
INNER JOIN tblaccounts AS acc1 ON acc1.accountID = tblFixtures.player1 INNER JOIN
   tblaccounts AS acc2 ON acc1.accountID = tblFixtures.player2
```

UPDATE

Your entire query should look like this. And `player1_name` and `player2_name` become the column names you can use in a GridView.

```
SELECT 
tblFixtures.player1,
(SELECT name FROM tblaccounts WHERE (accountID = tblFixtures.player1)) AS player1_name,
tblFixtures.player2,
(SELECT name FROM tblaccounts WHERE (accountID = tblFixtures.player2)) AS player2_name,
tblFixtures.compID, 
tblFixtures.round
FROM tblFixtures INNER JOIN tblCompetitions ON tblFixtures.compID = 
tblCompetitions.compID WHERE tblFixtures.compID = @Event_ID and round = 
@Round
```

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. I'm getting Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'. I put it in my code like this.. SELECT tblFixtures.player1, (SELECT contactName FROM tblaccounts WHERE (accountID = tblFixtures.player1)) AS player1name, SELECT tblFixtures.player2, (SELECT contactName FROM tblaccounts WHERE (accountID = tblFixtures.player1)) AS player2name, tblFixtures.compID, tblFixtures.round FROM tblFixtures INNER JOIN tblCompetitions ON tblFixtures.compID = tblCompetitions.compID ...

Comment: This `SELECT tblFixtures.player2` should be `tblFixtures.player2`. You can only have one select if it is not nested in `()`

Comment: Ooh I'm a bit lost sorry. Any chance you can edit that line for me please? Also, in Gridview I presume I then just put player1name and player1name as the datafields? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: See my upated answer